# JavaScript/DOM - Give a newly created element an ID

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I apply an element ID to a newly created element through JavaScript DOM?

The code I have written creates a table which is triggered from a button.

I need to apply a unique ID to this table so it can be styled differently to others which appear on my site.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
var tab = document.createElement("ViewShoppingCart");
document.getElementById("shopping_list").appendChild(tab);

var tbdy = document.createElement("tbody");
tab.id = "new_cart";
tab.appendChild(tbdy);
new_cart = true;

var total = 0;

for (var a = 0; a <= nameArray.length-1; a++) {

var tr = document.createElement("tr");
tbdy.appendChild(tr);

var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("x " + quantityArray[a]));
    tr.appendChild(td); 

var td2 = document.createElement("td");
    td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nameArray[a]));
    tr.appendChild(td2);

var td3 = document.createElement("td");
    td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sumArray[a]));
    tr.appendChild(td3);

}
```

Comment: `tab.id = "cart" + (new Date).getTime()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var tbdy = document.createElement("tbody");
tbdy.id = "newtbodyid";
tab.id = "new_cart";
tab.appendChild(tbdy);
new_cart = true;
```

Comment: I edited my answer, i assume `tbdy` is your table so just put the `tbdy.id = "newtbodyid";` after defining the var.

Comment: if your dynamically generated `table` is outside of the code scope, you can try either defining the id for it as shown above or through a `document.getElementById('tableID').setAttribute('id', 'newid');`. Note that the latter may not work that well in IE, if that is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

For applying styles consider using class selectors, you may not need IDs at all.

Note that if you want to create valid HTML you can't have duplicated IDs that significantly lessens value for CSS styles, especially for table data.